# android- XML OnClick Method not working

Tags: android, xml

I'm getting the following error:

```
04-16 14:29:02.281 4845-4845/com.example.rswat.mychatapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.rswat.mychatapp, PID: 4845
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid to: 
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.rswat.mychatapp.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:33)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Please help...! Thanks a lot...!

[image: code]

Comment: Please post your code..

Comment: We can't resolve the errors without the code. Add them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML Layout

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:onClick="buttonClick"
        android:text="@string/button" />
```

Activity Class

```
public void buttonClick(View view){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with the Firebase code, not the XML `onClick`-property. Try moving your Firebase code to the `onCreate`-method, and you'll see that the app crashes as well. Feel free to post the new Logcat log here.